# Remove rows and identifier in R

Tags: r, rows

I have a data frame where I want to remove specific rows so that I don't report on them, but I'm finding that, even though the rows are deleted, the items appear in the report with zero value.

For example, the following:

```
name <- c('a','b','c','d')
hight <- c('tall','short','tall','short')
df <- data.frame(name, hight)
summary(df$hight)
```

gives me the following output:

```
short  tall 
  2     2
```

After deleting the rows:

```
delRow<-which(df=='tall', arr.ind=T)[,1] 
df<-df[-delRow,]
summary(df$hight)
```

I get the following:

```
short  tall 
  2     0
```

How can I get rid of the column 'tall' altogether?

Comment: `summary(droplevels(df$hight))`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks A Webb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name <- c('a','b','c','d')
hight <- c('tall','short','tall','short')
df <- data.frame(name, hight)

df$hight <- as.character(df$hight)

delRow<-which(df=='tall', arr.ind=T)[,1] 
df<-df[-delRow,]
df$hight <- as.factor(df$hight)
summary(df$hight)
```

Gives me the following output:

```
short 
    2
```